# emacs: ruby mode after reindent-then-newline-and-indent

Tags: emacs, ruby-mode

i am using emacs 23.2 and reference configurations from purcell https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d
i met a problem when i am edit ruby file and rails file, see below[image]

steps:
1. move the cursor to somewhere
2. hit "RET" key to add more new line, then move the cursor to somewhere
3. the red space happened at the last new line.

do you know how to turn this mark off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your problem with this feature?  The red space goes away as soon as you
start typing doesn't it?

The feature is `show-trailing-whitespace`, and it's meant to help you see
spurious space at EOL.  Which is very helpful for team development
environment, as checking in such code will annoy your teammates.

What you should do is add a `before-save-hook` that removes spurious
whitespace see:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace#toc3

code:

```ruby
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)
```

If you want to disable `show-trailing-whitespace` as well:

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))
```

Comment: no, it only appears when i am hit "RET" key to add more new line between two blocks. this is the step:<br />
1. move the cursor to somewhere<br />
2. hit "RET" key to add more new line, then move the cursor to somewhere<br />
3. the red space happened at the last new line.<br />

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look at the [ws-trim.el](ftp://ftp.lysator.liu.se/pub/emacs/ws-trim.el) library, which removes trailing whitespace from lines which you edit, but by default does not remove them from other lines*.

I find this best for version-control (compared to deleting all trailing whitespace upon saving), as you do not introduce changes in other people's work if you edit the same file.

(*) although it is also nicely configurable if you want it to do more than that.